# Peewee - update issue with records with ForeignKeyField('self')

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I have a database that I am filling from a pd.DataFrame. One of the classes has a ForeignKeyField('self').

```
    from peewee import SqliteDatabase, Model
    from peewee import IntegerField, CharField, ForeignKeyField, BooleanField
    import pandas as pd

    db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:', pragmas=(('foreign_keys', 'on'),))

    class BaseModel(Model):
        class Meta:
            database = db

    class Team(BaseModel):
        id = IntegerField(unique = True, primary_key = True)
        name = CharField()
        reserve_team = BooleanField()
        parent_team = ForeignKeyField('self', related_name = 'reserve_teams', null = True)
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'team_team'

    Team.create_table()
```

The dataframe I am filling from looks something like this

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
                       'Name': ['A','A2','B','C','C2'],
                       'Reserve': [False, True, False, False, True],
                       'Parent': [None, 'A', None, None, 'C']})
```

I use the following code to fill the table. The parent_team is set to None and when the table is filled I intend to go back and update this field where appropriate.

```
    data = []
    for row in df.itertuples():
        data.append((row.ID,
                     row.Name,
                     row.Reserve == True,
                     None))
    fields = [Team.id,
              Team.name,
              Team.reserve_team,
              Team.parent_team]
    with db.atomic():
        Team.insert_many(data, fields = fields).execute()
```

My problem is that I don't understand how to do this without looping over the dataframe/table combination. The documentation seems pretty clear that this should never be done.

```
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if row.Reserve:
            r = row.ID
            p = row.Parent
            Team.update(parent_team = Team.get(Team.name == p)).where(Team.id == r).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a topo-sort of the data and then insert them directly with the parent IDs.

As far as looping and updating -- some ideas:

- wrap in a transaction
- use ValuesList() to provide the mapping of id->parent id and update all at once
- insert id -> parent id into a temp table and update using the temp table (all at once)

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. My actual use case is a little bit more complicated with several foreign keys similar to the one described in the question. In the example are you suggesting that I do not use insert_many()? If looping, what exactly do you mean by wrapping in transaction? Sorry for the follow-up questions but very new to this.

Comment: After some thought I now get your first idea, thanks. Still unclear about the transaction and ValuesList() though.